# Harmful to eat meat from livestock/animals with high levels of cortisol (stress) hormone?

Tags: stress, taste, meat, livestock, cortisol

**Is it harmful for humans to eat meat from livestock/animals with high levels of  stress hormones? Or does it just change the quality and taste of the meat** (and not necessarily harmful for human consumption)?

How to know if the meat you purchased is from an animal that may have endured stress?